# Delete the last value of dynamically allocated array in C

Tags: c

**The question is in the title**

```
void deleteLastValue(dynIntArray* t){ //function should responds to unexpected values
    if(t->tab == NULL){ //if the array is empty we should return an error
       fprintf(stderr,"The array is empty");
       exit(1);
    }
    t->tab[(t->size)-1] = 0; /**I'm not sure what to do here should I free the pointer using free function**/
    //t->tab[(t->size)-1] = NULL; is it necessary ?
    //free(t->tab[(t->size)-1]); 
    t->tab = (int*)realloc(t->tab,((t->size)-1)*sizeof(int)); //we reallocate but with the new size
    t->size--;//size - 1; but capacity stills the same
}

typedef struct{ //structure of an dynamic array
    int * tab; //an array of 
    unsigned int capacity; // the space in memory
    unsigned int size;// size of array
} dynIntArray;
```

If you can review my code, I had issues with what to do with the last element of the array. And should I do more if I  want the program to respond to unexpected inputs to make it work properly. Thank you.
You are awesome!

Comment: I think it's enough to do `t->size--`.

Comment: If you reallocate, then the capacity is not the same. All you really need to do, if you want to keep the capacity, is decrease the size. Nothing more.

Comment: What about the last element, what should I do with it ?

Comment: @theo.agnostos you should nothing with it. Does your code work as expected? What is your actual question? Maybe you should post a [mcve] and tell us what issues you have. You should also tell us what requirements exactly you have.

Comment: theo.agnostos, Provide more detail on the roles of `capacity` and ``size`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparenty it's not quite clear to you how `capacity` and `size` are related.

`realloc` can be a pretty expensive function that may take quite some time. So if you call `realloc` each and every time the size changes your code will work, but it might be pretty slow. Therefore the `capacity` is used.

Roughly it is done like this:

- You initialize the dynamic array with a `size` = 0 and `capacity` = 100 (or some appropriate value larger than 0).
- Now you can add 100 elements to the array without `realloc` ever being called.
- If you add one element more, you add 100 to `capacity` and you call `realloc`
- Now the capacity is 200 and you can add another 100 elements without `realloc` being called.

If you want to decrease the size of the dynamic array, you just can decrease `size` without calling `realloc` leaving `capacity` alone.
If the difference between `size` and `capacity` becomes larger than some value or maybe if the `capacity` is larger than twice the `size`, then you can decrease the capacity and call `realloc`

There are several strategies about how `size` and `capacity` are related and when to increase/decrease `capacity`.

```
void deleteLastValue(dynIntArray* t) {
  if (t->tab == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The array is empty");
    exit(1);
  }

  t->size--;   // that's all you need to do    

  // now optionally you might want to decrease the capacity
  // if the capacity is larger than twice the size
  // or based on some other strategy

  if (t->capacity >  2 * t->size)
  {
    t->capacity = t->size;
    t->tab = realloc(t->tab, t->capacity);
    if (t->tab == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "realloc error in deleteLastValue");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware that you still need to check if the array is empty (IOW if `size` is 0. I leave this as an exercise.

---

If you want more information, you should show us the other functions.

Review of *your* function:

```
void deleteLastValue(dynIntArray* t) { 
  if (t->tab == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The array is empty");
    exit(1);
  }
  t->tab[(t->size) - 1] = 0;  // this is useless, the element is no longer part of the array
                              // you don't need to overwrite it with 0

  // the call to free below is completly wrong, t->tab[(t->size) - 1] is not a pointer but an int
  // free(t->tab[(t->size) - 1]); 

  // this reallocation is correct (except there is no error checking and the (int*) cast is useless)
  t->tab = (int*)realloc(t->tab, ((t->size) - 1) * sizeof(int));
  t->size--;

  // you leave the capacity alone which is maybe what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you `realloc` every time, you only need the size of the array. You can also use a flexible array simplifying the allocation and deallocation.

```
typedef struct{ //structure of an dynamic array
    unsigned int size;// size of array
    int tab[]; //an array of 
} dynIntArray;


dynIntArray *deleteLastValue(dynIntArray* t)
{
    if(t && t -> size)
    {
        t = realloc(sizeof(*t) + (t -> size - 1) * sizeof(t -> tab[0]));
        if(t) t -> size--;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: there is no VLA in this code

Comment: @tstanisl, yes it's not a VLA, it's called [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Answer (score 0):

Thank y'all! It worked perfectly fine. I submit the **answer** here for posterity. (For the sake of the exercise we don't need to change the capacity)

```
void deleteLastValue(dynIntArray* t){
    if(t->tab == NULL || t->size == 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"The array is empty");
        exit(1);
    }
    t->size--;
}
```